# Drag&drop from explorer delete my source file

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I work on a Outlook plugin, and i want to drop a file in a listbox (in a outlook region) from explorer. I simply do this:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{    
    this._shareList.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this._shareList_DragDrop);
    this._shareList.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this._shareList_DragEnter);
}

private void _shareList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false) == true)
   {
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
       Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow;
   }
}

private void _shareList_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] tab = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    foreach (string filePath in tab)
        AttachFile(new FileInfo(filePath));
}
```

When i drop file from the explorer, the source file is deleted of the disk! Why? Outlook catch the drop event?

So how can i prevent that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: instead of using `e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link`, try using `DragDropEffects.Copy`, see if that fixes the problem

Comment: I have already try, no difference :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I do an error in my code :(
I delete unfortunately the file...

Sorry to bother you.